# Generic types, Interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I would like to create a generic notification engine. The idea is to have a single core engine to process any type of notification. This engine will process notification and handle all logging, error handling etc..

I created 3 simple interfaces:

```
public interface INotificationInput
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Friendly Name for logging/tracing usage
    /// </summary>
    string FriendlyName { get; set; }

    string NotificationCode{ get; set; }

    Double Version { get; set; } 
}

public  interface INotificationOutput
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Friendly Name for logging/tracing usage
    /// </summary>
    string FriendlyName { get; }
}

public interface INotificationProvider<out Toutput, Tinput> where Toutput : INotificationOutput where Tinput : INotificationInput
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Friendly Name for logging/tracing usage
    /// </summary>
    string FriendlyName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates and returns an INotificationOutput from data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Toutput GenerateNotificationOutput(Tinput data);
}
```

So the INotificationProvider will chunk the INotificationInput to create a INotificationOutput.

That could be information to send a email, a sms, you name it, the engine will call the methods and do the magic of scheduling, logging, handling errors and so on..

I implemented the interface like this:

```
/// <summary>
    /// INotificationInput represented by a dummy object
    /// </summary>
    public class DummyNotificationInput : INotificationInput
    {
        public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
        public string NotificationCode { get; set; }
        public double Version { get; set; }
    }

public class DummyNotificationOutput : INotificationOutput
{
    public string FriendlyName { get; private set; }
}

public class DummyProvider : INotificationProvider<DummyNotificationOutput, DummyNotificationInput>
{
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }

    public DummyNotificationOutput GenerateNotificationOutput(DummyNotificationInput data)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now I would like my engine to have a list of provider:

```
 var providersList = new List<INotificationProvider<INotificationOutput, INotificationInput>>();
```

The problem is that I cannot to the following:

```
providersList.Add(new DummyProvider<DummyNotificationOutput, DummyNotificationInput>());
```

There must be a solution. Am I using the wrong approach?

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error?

Comment: side note: `Double Version { get; set; } ` is not good choice since  comparing `double` with `==` is a bad practice.

Comment: What does adding the interfaces generically to `INotificationProvider` and then constraining them to a particular type give you, that you can't just get by making `INofiticationProvider` take `INotificationInput` and output `INotificationOutput` explicitly. I think you are trying to be too complex with the interfaces. When creating a list of notification providers, the only thing the list will have in common is `INotificationProvider` which doesn't know what type the implementor is.. so what do you gain?

Comment: Basically, what I'm saying is - why make `INotificationProvider` generic in the first place - what do you want the API to look like when you "use" the provider instances that you have placed in `providersList`? What are you trying to gain by doing this? If you show the expected use case, the means to get there might become clear

Answer (score 3):

The second generic type argument to `INotificationProvider` isn't covariant (at a conceptual level), but you're trying to use it as if it were.  It is actually contravariant.

In your list of `INotificationProvider` objects you've defined the input notification as an `INotificationInput`.  This means objects added to this list need to be able to accept *any type of `INotificationInput` as input to their `GenerateNotificationOutput` function*.  You're trying to add an object that only knows how to handle `DummyNotificationInput` objects.  It would fail if it were passed some other type of input.

Either your provider needs to accept `INotificationInput` objects, if you want to be able to add it to that list, or the list needs to define all of the objects as accepting `DummyNotificationInput`.

Answer (score 0):

As Servy has already answered, you can't really do this due to what you `providersList` is expecting

With this in mind, it may actually be simpler to just make `INotificationProvider` non-generic:

```
public interface INotificationProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Friendly Name for logging/tracing usage
    /// </summary>
    string FriendlyName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates and returns an INotificationOutput from data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    INotificationOutput GenerateNotificationOutput(INotificationInput data);
}
```

Then the `DummyProvider` becomes:

```
public class DummyProvider : INotificationProvider
{
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }

    public INotificationOutput GenerateNotificationOutput(INotificationInput data)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now, probably not what you had in mind - you are expecting to pass `DummyNotificationInput` instances to `DummyProvider`

You could just type check in your `Provider` code

```
public class DummyProvider : INotificationProvider
{
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }

    public INotificationOutput GenerateNotificationOutput(INotificationInput data)
    {
        if (!(data is DummyNotificationInput)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid type specified", "data");

        return something...;
    }
}
```

Obviously, you lose design time checking - but if you really need to put them in a covariant list you can't provide an implementor that has a derived generic type argument